# Always receive 401 when accessing api with a valid token

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Starting with the following repo at https://github.com/mjrousos/IdentityServer4Authentication, I added a "ValuesController" with a single "Get" method with the [Authorize] attribute.  When I login using the web front end I'm able to access this endpoint just fine - the web bits contain the standard web bits found in the IS4 Quickstarts.

However, when I request a token from the token endpoint (/connect/token) with the following body (raw) "grant_type=password&username=gvdonovan%40gmail.com&password=Pass20!7&client_id=myClient&scope=myAPIs" and then use this token in a Get request with a single Authorization header with a value of "bearer [my token]" I receive a 401 Unauthorized response.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your Identity Server and your 'protected controllers' in the same project, with a single startup, which is a configuration I'm not used to.

For our use of IdSvr, we made sure that the startup for the client (a web api) used the middleware "UseIdentityServerAuthentication" in the configure method, with appropriate definitions for what the acceptable Authority and AllowedScopes are for that client.
Then the use of the Authorize header on protected API resources will auto-magically call the authority (our IdSvr) to verify the token.

Our IdSvr doesn't have controllers or "app.UseMvc", because it is just for issuing/verifying tokens.